# Intermittent and continuous SSLHandshakeException while connecting to android.googleapis.com/gcm/

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We are facing some issues in connecting to Google’s  GCM API (https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send ) for Android push notifications from our server (SSLHandshakeException). 
From 28th February to 8th March 2018 the issue was intermittent(push sent sometimes, SSL handshake error otherwise). From 9th March 2018 the issue is continuous.

Please see the logs below. Would like to know if there was any changes to the issued certificates.

> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>           at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)

Comment: you have not provided logs, you've provided an error message. SO is not a IT service. The error message is pretty clear, It Cannot find a valid Certificate

Comment: The issue is, GCM push notifications to android devices were working perfectly before. Checked the validity of existing certificate, which is till 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to GeoTrust to GoogleTrust migration of the SSL certificates for googleapis.com. Issue got fixed when we imported new certificate from the URL: https://android.googleapis.com and added to our server's trust store.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand the details, but when I update our push provider/server "External Services Certs" and add the cert below.. my push started working again. So even though the Equifax cert that I originally installed 2 years ago was working until a few weeks ago, something changed on the GCM server and that cert was no longer valid. It has an expiration date of Aug 2018, which is near, but should not expire till that date.

I did notice that the new cert is SHA256 and the original is SHA1, so maybe this is a required security upgrade. It kind of screws me since my push content providers are distributed, not in a single location where it is easy to update the cert :(

The cert that fixed my issue is:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

I obtained it by running this openssl cmd and it is the second one in the chain. That CAfile parm is robably not needed, since I did not have that file and there was a complaint, but the required cert chain was still displayed.

openssl s_client -connect gcm-http.googleapis.com:443/gcm/send -debug -showcerts -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer

Answer (score 0):

Kari - that is what I figured. Thanks for replying.. but the URL you list gives 404.. can you double check and update if you have the correct URL.

Comment: Yes, even though the link shows 404, you would still be able to view and import the certificate using the same url for googleapis from the browser.

Answer (score -1):

I am seeing the same issue and the same SSL error. Any more discussion on this?

Comment: Consider using the comments section `add a comment` for the followup questions or edit the post. Please avoid adding these to `post answer`